# C++11 object composition with abstract classes

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have a class Foo that has a const member of an abstract class Bar, what is the correct way to pass Bar in the constructor to initialize the const member?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(?Bar? bar): bar(?bar?) {};
private:
    const ?Bar? bar;
}
```

In C++11 I was thinking of using std::unique_ptr like so:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar> &bar): bar(std::move(bar)) {};
private:
    const std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar;
}
```

Is this the best way to do it? What are the other ways and when should I use them?

Comment: it seems `const Bar*` will work, right? Any thoughts on the reason to use `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this (I would not use the reference, since it is already a "pointer"). What problems are you anticipating, or what problems did you encounter?

Comment: If you are going to opt for `std::unique_ptr`, I find it better if you take the argument by value. It will enable you to pass temporaries, and for non-temporaries user code will have to explicitly `std::move` the argument making it clearer that your constructor is stealing the contents of the `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: I think passing `std::unique_ptr` by rvalue reference is better. But you should definitely not take it by non-const lvalue reference if you're going to `move` from it.

Answer (score 0):

In...

```
struct Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar> &bar): bar(std::move(bar)) {};
    const std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar;
};
```

... bar (the pointer) is not modifiable, but the value to which is points is.

Is this what you want?

I would rather think:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<const Bar>& bar): bar(std::move(bar)) {}

private
    std::unique_ptr<const Bar> bar;
};
```

would be more appropriate, as not the value is truly constant. I suspect that this won't compile because the unique_ptr cannot call the destructor (specification of custom deleter springs to mind), but the value to which bar points is const, which is what you really want (I suspect).